# Reactjs &Typescript: how to show result from API call?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to show result of API call in reactjs & typescript. In the following code, first segmentation is the API call and the second segmentation is for show result in the UI. Both segmentation are in one file:

First segmentation:

```
  const upload = React.useCallback(async () => {
        try {
          const response = await mymethod(
           
            user,
            pass,
            onUpload
          );
          setSuccess(true);
          setUploading(false);
         
          return { body: response.data};    
        }              
      }, [
        pass,
        user,       
      ]      
      );
```

second segmentation:

```
  return (
        <AuthLayout showInfo={true}>
          <div className={classes.root}>                
              <Container>
                <Box
                  display="flex"
                  flexDirection="column"
                  alignItems="center"                    
                >
                  {uploading ? (
                    <>
                      <BorderLinearProgress
                        variant="determinate"
                        value={progress}
                      />
                    
                    </>
                  ) : success ? (
                    <>
                      <CheckCircleOutline
                        className={classes.successIcon}
                        fontSize="inherit"
                      />        
                      <div>
                      **// I want to show result of call API here**
                    </div>                        
    
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <>                         
                   
                    </>
                  )}
                </Box>
              </Container>
            </Box>
          </div>
        </AuthLayout>
      );
```

How to show result of the API call ( return { body: response.data};    ) in the second segmentation? response.data is a json with following key: message & validity.

Thank you for your attention....

Comment: It looks like you already know how to set and read state values.  Why aren't you just doing that with the result of your API call?  Why are you trying to handle it differently than your `success` and `uploading` values?

Comment: I am an intern in the react & typescript and now I am reviewing the code of others to increase my knowledge. I do not know how to use the output of the API in the <div> tag in the second segmentation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply... You'd do the same thing you're already doing with other values.  Notice how you have state values presumably declared like this:

```
const [success, setSuccess] = useState();
```

And you set the values in your API call:

```
setSuccess(true);
```

And you read the values in your rendering.

So what you'd do to use the values from your API call is... declare your state, set your state, read your state.  Same thing.  For example:

```
const [apiResult, setAPIResult] = useState();
```

And:

```
setAPIResult(response.data);
```

And in the render, perhaps something like:

```
{
  apiResult ? (
    <>
      render values from apiResult in this markup
    </>
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: Did I get it right? you mean :‌  const [apiResult, setAPIResult] = useState();                            const upload = React.useCallback(async () => {
      //Same code as before 
      );  and in the second seg: success ? (
                    <>                            
                      <div>
                    {setAPIResult.message}
                    </div>                        
    
                    </>
                  )

Comment: @lida: No.  What is `setAPIResult.message`?  What are you expecting that to do and why?  In the code where you have a result from your API call, you'd call the "set" function for your state value and set the API result to that state value.  Then you'd read that state value in the render.  Exactly as you *already do* with your two `uploading` and `success` state values.  There's no difference.

Comment: response.data is a json with following key: message & validity. I what to show message & validity to the user

Comment: @lida: Ok, then in your rendering you would presumably want to use the values `apiResult.message` and/or `apiResult.validity`.  Did you try?  What didn't work?

Comment: Yes i tried it but it throw an error: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339). I edit my code as following: In first seg: const [apiResult, setAPIResult] = useState(); const upload = React.useCallback(async () => { //Same code as before );   and in second seg:  apiResult ? (
                    <>
                      <div>
                      {apiResult.message}
                    </div>                        
    
                    </>

Comment: @lida: With TypeScript you may need to define the type for the state value.  What is the type of `response.data`?  Ideally it would be that.  If the type isn't known then you may need to use `any`.  For example: `const [apiResult, setAPIResult] = useState<any>();`

Comment: fixed. Thank you sincerely and deeply. I searched the internet before my question, but unfortunately I did not find it due to my lack of knowledge.